# Git Beginner: Separating Git Commits

Tags: git, github

Beginner Question:

I have been recently doing a lot of development locally and then did a git pull today (I know I should have done pulls more often) and pulled in lots of changes and different conflicts. I fixed the conflict and squashed all my commits into 1 (with the pulled commits interspersed). Now I have a huge commit when I send out for review with the changes of the pulled commits as well. I am trying to find a way to solve this and separate out my commits from those commits.

Example:

My Commits:

original -> A1 -> A2 -> A3

Remote Commits:

original -> B1 -> B2 -> B3

Merged:

original -> A1 -> B1 -> A2 -> B2 -> A3 -> B3

Using Git Rebase, I squashed the commits into 1 commit, C1:

original -> C1

Now my commit covers all the changes from A1 to A3 and B1 to B3.

Any Ideas how to separate out the changes or fix this?

Comment: you need to add a lot more information about what commands you did that led to your changes being squashed and interspersed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Andrew C noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172787/git-beginner-separating-git-commits#comment41034528_26172787), you can help out answer-ers by showing the actual commands you used.  In this case, though, I can guess what you did.

You started with your local repo in sync with `origin`, like this:

```
...- o   <-- HEAD=develop, origin/develop
```

This tip-of-branch commit `o` is what you labeled `original`.  (I had to guess here that the branch is named `develop` and tracks `origin/develop` so these might not be the same names you have.)

Over time, you made changes, `git add`ed the resulting work files, and `git commit`ed, to produce this:

```
         A1 - A2 - A3   <-- HEAD=develop
       /
...- o                  <-- origin/develop
```

Note that the "commit pointing to another commit" arrows here should all point *left*ward, not rightward: `A3` points to `A2`, `A2` points to `A1`, and `A1` points to `o`.  The reason is simple: the "pointing" is done by storing the previous commit's SHA-1 ID in the new commit.  Once a commit is actually stored in the repository, it can *never* be changed.  This means `A1` cannot point to a commit that does not yet exist (such as `A2`) when `A1` is created; it can only point to a commit that *does* exist (such as `o` above).  Later, when `A2` is created, it can point back to `A1` since that now exists, but `A1` cannot be changed to point to `A2`.<sup>1</sup>

**The fact that commits can never be changed is crucial to your recovery.**  We'll get back to this in a bit.

Next, you ran `git pull`, which you have not re-configured in any way, so `git pull` ran `git fetch` (as it always does) and then `git merge` (as it does if you don't tell it to rebase instead).  The `fetch` step obtained some new commits from `origin`:<sup>2</sup>

```
         A1 - A2 - A3   <-- HEAD=develop
       /
...- o - B1 - B2 - B3   <-- origin/develop
```

and the `merge` step added a merge commit, combining "their stuff" with "your stuff", on your current branch (`develop`):

```
         A1 - A2 - A3 - M  <-- HEAD=develop
       /              /
...- o - B1 - B2 - B3      <-- origin/develop
```

If you run `git log` without `--graph` it likes to sort commits by date order, so depending on timing, you could see these as:

```
M    merged origin/develop into develop
B3   their message for B3
A3   your message for A3
B2   [etc]
A2
B1
A1
o
```

which is how you described them (but with the arrows pointing the wrong way, again).  In fact, though, the parent/child relationship is determined by the commit graph.  If you use `git log` *with* `--graph`, the `log` command sorts according to the graph first, and will show the commits in a more sensible (graph-wise anyway) order, rather than "date/time of commit" order.

You then probably—again, I must guess—used `git rebase -i` and changed a whole lot of `pick` commands to `squash`.  While rebase is often described as "changing" or "rewriting" commits, what it really does is *copy* commits.  It must, because commits cannot be changed.  So for each commit, rebase starts by copying what that commit did (but without quite committing), then makes some change—usually a small one, but optionally a very big one—and only then makes a new commit out of the result.  When you tell rebase to `squash`, it delays<sup>3</sup> the previous commit until the to-be-squashed commit's changes are also included.  By squashing all commits, the new copy is just one single commit, which contains all the work done by every commit (`A1` through `A3` plus `B1` through `B3` plus the merge `M`).

The result is the one new commit `C1`, as you noted.  However, since this is a *new* commit, and git retains old commits for a month or so by default, the *old* commits are still in there.  What git has done is make your `develop` branch-name point to the new commit:

```
         A1 - A2 - A3 - M  <-- [invisible, but still there]
       /              /
...- o - B1 - B2 - B3      <-- origin/develop
       \
         C1                <-- HEAD=develop
```

According to your question, you want to restore `develop` to point to either `M` or `A3` (it's not really clear which).  As long as they are still in your repository, this is easy to do: the only trick required is to find the SHA-1 for either `M` or `A3` (whichever you want to restore).

Sometimes, that SHA-1 is still in a window in scrollback, so you can just scroll back and copy it.

If not, though, you can use git's "reflogs".

Each of your branches has a reflog, and there is an additional reflog for `HEAD` itself.  The command `git reflog` will show you the contents of a specific reflog, or `HEAD` by default:

```
git reflog develop
```

The output is much like that from `git log` (in fact `git reflog` just invokes `git log` with several options, including `-g`, which is the short version of `--walk-reflogs`).  That will let you find the SHA-1 you want.

Once you're *sure* you have the right SHA-1, and also that your work tree is clean (has nothing to commit), check out the branch you want re-set—you're probably already on it, but `git checkout develop`, assuming the branch is `develop`, won't hurt anything, and will just say `Already on branch 'develop'` in this case—use `git reset --hard sha1`:

```
git reset --hard 1234567
```

(assuming it's `1234567` of course).  This will make your current branch, which we just made sure is `develop`, point to commit `1234567`.  That is, now instead of `M` being invisible—I'll assume `1234567` was the ID of `M`—it is `C1` that is invisible:

```
         A1 - A2 - A3 - M  <-- HEAD=develop
       /              /
...- o - B1 - B2 - B3      <-- origin/develop
       \
         C1                <-- [invisible]
```

Now it is `C1` that is only in the reflogs, instead of `M`.

If you `reset --hard` to the ID of `A3`, `develop` will point to `A3`, making both `M` *and* `C1` invisible:

```
                   A3      <-- HEAD=develop
                 /    \
         A1 - A2        M  <-- [invisible]
       /              /
...- o - B1 - B2 - B3      <-- origin/develop
       \
         C1                <-- [invisible]
```

This is the same graph as before; all we did was change the place that `develop` points.  (`HEAD` just contains the name `develop` in all cases.  With each command, git opens the file `HEAD`, sees that it says "develop", and promptly ignores `HEAD` and works with `develop` directly instead.)

---

Once you have your old state back, it's up to you how to proceed from there.  The usual recommendation, for code reviews, is to `git rebase` your work onto the tip of the new development branch.  As before, `rebase` simply *copies*; let's copy `A1` through `A3` (leaving the invisible `M` totally invisible this time):

```
         A1 - A2 - A3
       /
...- o - B1 - B2 - B3                     <-- origin/develop
                      \
                        A1' - A2' - A3'   <-- HEAD=develop
```

Here, the "prime" or `'` mark in `A1'`, etc., signifies that these are copies (with whatever changes are needed to, first, make them apply to `B3` rather than `o`, and second, point back to `B3`, then to `A1'`, and so on).

When code branches have "diverged too much", however, it may be better to review a merge proposal, i.e., to review the sequence that ends with the merge `M`.  That's not a question with a single right answer: it's up to both you, and whoever is reviewing / accepting code, how to do this.  (It's also up to you, plural, to agree as to what "diverged too much" even *means*.)

---

<sup>1</sup>To really complete the picture for why the arrows must point "backwards", note that the SHA-1 ID of a commit is a crypographic checksum of the *contents* of that commit, including a time-stamp for the commit.  So the ID is only known once the commit is complete: you can't predict the future commit-ID without creating it.

<sup>2</sup>The diagram here assumes you have a newer version of git.  In all versions, `git pull` does in fact use `git fetch`, but in older versions, the way `git pull` invokes `git fetch` tells `git fetch` not to update the `origin/develop` remote-tracking branch.  If you run `git fetch` manually, it does update the remote branch; and with versions 1.8.4 or higher, it updates the remote branch even when run from `git pull`.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, `rebase` actually makes the intermediate commits, then resets one back, so you get a whole bunch of intermediate commits.  It just *looks like* it delays the commit.  This fits with git's internal philosophy of committing as often as possible. :-)